bounded sum implies bounded coefficients for a fixed basis
Studying other topics from functional analysis I got stuck with this supposed easy issue from linear algebra that could be formulated like this:
Let $X$ a finite dimensional normed space and $x_1,\dots,x_n$ a fixed basis of $X$. If $||a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n||\leq M$, then each $a_i$ must be bounded.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advanced

Have you tried $n=2$ ?

As $X$ is a finite dimensional vector space, the set $K=\{v= \sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k\mid ||v||\leq M  \}$ is compact in $X$. Using the norm equivalence for finite dimensional vector spaces we know that function  $||\sum_{k=1}^na_k x_k||_\infty := \max_{k=1,\dots,n}|a_k|$ is continuous. Every continuous function on a compact domain has an maximum. Thus, yes  there is an upper bound for all $|a_i|$.

I see the key is the equivalence of norms in finite dimension. Thank you very much
